# mean distance from a point in a circle to its boundary ( circumference)?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, circles, plane-geometry, means

I have perused the solution to the average distance from a point in a ball to a point on its boundary. I don't quite understand it. However, it seems likely that the analogous problem 'Average distance  from a point in a circle  to the circumference (boundary)' may be easier to solve. This is the problem that I want to solve.

Comment: So you want to find the average distant from a point inside a circle to the boundary of the circle?  If so, you may without loss of generality assuming the point is of the form $(x,0)$ and the circle is of radius $r.$  Then the desired average value is $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int^{2\pi}_0  \sqrt{  (r\cos t - x)^2 + r^2 \sin^2 t} \ dt.$

Comment: John Murphy: Please clarify in your question whether you want to take a specific point inside, and then average the distance from it to the various points on the circle boundary, or on the other hand you want to take each point inside, find its closest distance to the circle boundary, and then average those closest distances. The answers will be different.

Answer (score 1):

For the unit circle, the distance from a point inside to the circumference is $1-r.$ If this is integrated using polar coordinates to get the average distance, one would integrate $(1-r)rdr\ d\theta$ over the interior of the circle, then divide by the area of the circle to get the average distance.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what we are averaging.   Are we averaging the distance from  particular interior point to all boundary points or are we averaging over all interior points?

Comment: @mattbiesecker I was doing it as the second choice of your comment, averaging the distance over all interior points. If one fixes a particular interior point $(a,b)$ inside the circle the average distance to a point $(x,y)$ chosen uniformly on the circle's boundary would be more difficult to find, and of course would be some expression involving $a,b$ (or at least involving the distance from $(a,b)$ to the circle center). IMO the question posted doesn't make it clear which computation is desired.

Comment: Yeah, the integral in my comment above to the OP cannot be evaluated in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make clear what am I solving.

If we have a circle with radius $R$ then the center is at a distance $R$ from any point on the circumference, therefore, the average distance of the center to the circumference is also $R$.

If we take a point $P$ other than the center then it will be closer to some points on the circumference and further from others than it would be if $P$ where on the center of the circle. I understand that the question asks what would be the average distance from this point $P$ to all the points on the circumference.

Assuming that I've understood correctly, then matt biesecker's answer is correct and I'll elaborate on why.

First, let $P$ have coordinates $(h, 0)$. If $P$ didn't have those coordinates we could simply rotate the circle to make it have that position.

Now, a point on the circumference will have coordinates $(x, y)$.

We know that the distance between two points is given by $d = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$.

Substituing the coordinates of our point inside the circle and our arbitray point on the circumference we get the following:
\begin{equation}
d = \sqrt{(x-h)^2 + y^2}
\end{equation}

If we use polar coordinates this will become way easier, let's recall that, to convert from Cartesian to polar coordinates we have:

$x = r\,Cos(\theta)$

$y = r\, Sin(\theta)$

In this particular case, because we want all the points to be on the circumference with radius $R$ we get:

$x = R\,Cos(\theta)$

$y = R\, Sin(\theta)$

Pluging this in our expression for distance we get:

\begin{equation}
d(\theta) = \sqrt{(R\,Cos(\theta)-h)^2 + (R\,Sin(\theta))^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
d(\theta) = \sqrt{(R\,Cos(\theta)-h)^2 + R^2 \, Sin^2(\theta)}
\end{equation}

This last expression lets us find the distance between our point $P$ and any point on the circumference with radius $R$ at an angle $\theta$.

But we don't want that, do we? We whant the average distance from $P$ to all of the points on the circumference. Let's recall how to get the average value of a function:

\begin{equation}
\bar{f(x)} = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b} f(x)
\end{equation}

In our problem, $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, in this case we get:

\begin{equation}
\bar{d} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{(R\,Cos(\theta)-h)^2 + R^2 \, Sin^2(\theta)} \, d\theta
\end{equation}

Which is equivalent to matt biesecker's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building from Bernardo Morales' foundation:

Consider a Circle with radius $R$ centered at the origin of a polar coordinate plane.
Let $P$ be a point such that $P = (h,0)$. $P$ is the point from which we will measure the average distance to the circumference.

Represent points in the circle as $Q = (R,\theta)$ such that $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ and label the distance between $P$ and $Q$ as $D$. From the law of cosines, we get:

$$
D^2=R^2+h^2-2Rh\cos\theta
$$
$$
D = \sqrt{R^2+h^2-2Rh\cos\theta}
$$

Since $D$ is a function of $\theta$, we can find the average value of $D$ as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$:

$$
\bar{D}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi D(\theta) d\theta
$$
$$
\bar{D}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sqrt{R^2+h^2-2Rh\cos\theta}\cdot d\theta
$$

Here, $\theta$ ranges only from $0$ to $\pi$ because of the symmetry of the circle about the line $\theta=0$. This is equivalent to the solutions provided by Bernardo Morales and matt biesecker.